# Get first element in protractor

Tags: css-selectors, protractor

I want to verify the number of table rows in protractor, on a page in which tables of this type appear more than once. I've been trying to use the `first-of-type` selector, but it seems to be catching both tables because they do not appear side by side.

For example, given this HTML:

```
<div>
  <table class="foo">
    <tr>
      <th>First row</th>
      <th>Second row</th>
      <th>Third row</th>
      <th>Fourth row</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div>
  <table class="foo">
    <tr>
      <th>First row</th>
      <th>Second row</th>
      <th>Third row</th>
      <th>Fourth row</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

And this protractor code:

```
element.all(by.css('table:first-of-type tr:first-of-type th')).then(function (elements) {
  expect(elements.length).toBe(4);
});
```

Protractor is failing on the grounds that there are 8 elements and not 4. It seems the `table:first-of-type` selector is catching both elements, since they're both the first children of their parent `div` components. My project is structured in such a way that it's better not to add individual classes to each wrapping `div`.

Is there a way to get the first element found in Protractor and then search its child elements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have not used `:first-of-type` as a css selector in Protractor; however, you could get the [first](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.first) `table` with all `th`'s and then check to see if the [count](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.count) is 4.

```
expect(element.all(by.css('table')).first().all(by.css('th')).count()).toBe(4);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can certainly do it the way @cnishina suggested (and I would actually prefer his approach over making a long CSS selector), but if you want to continue using a single CSS selector for this problem, you should also apply the `first-of-type` (or `first-child`) to the parent `div`:

```
div:first-of-type > table:first-of-type > tr:first-of-type > th
```

I've also added the `>` to enforce the *direct parent-child relationships*.

Comment: Should be accepted answer...for my point of view